# How can I save, rename and get the saved location of the barcode?

Tags: php, barcode

I'm creating a registration system when an applicant register the system will automatically create a barcode for the applicant and save it to the folder "Barcode".

I'm using [barcodePHP](http://barcodebakery.com/)

My problem is I dont know how to save it to a folder, getting the saved location for using echo to display the barcode and renaming the barcode picture.

This is my code:

```
require('class/BCGColor.php');
require('class/BCGDrawing.php');
require('class/BCGcode39.barcode.php');

$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

// Barcode Part
$code = new BCGcode39();
$code->setScale(2);
$code->setThickness(30);
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black);
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white);
$code->setFont($font);
$code->setChecksum(false);
$code->parse($encoded);

// Drawing Part
$drawing = new BCGDrawing('', $color_white);
$drawing->setBarcode($code);
$drawing->draw();

 $drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);
```

Comment: Thank you sir Nanne for the edit

Comment: What does `$drawing->finish(BCGDrawing::IMG_FORMAT_PNG);` return? If it returns the raw image data - have you tried `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Not yet sir I'm new at using this. and I didnt see file_put_contents in there manual.

Comment: It's a normal PHP function, you can [read about it here](http://uk1.php.net/file_put_contents).

Comment: I already fix the save part the only problem is how can I save it to desired folder